# Delegate for generic class and method with generic return type

Tags: c#, delegates

When using delegate with generic classes, have an issue. Class is generic but method is not. However method return type is generic type.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public long CreateUserId { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : BaseEntity {

}

class Program {
    private delegate object MyDelegate(long id);
    private static MyDelegate _myHandler;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var genericType = typeof(TestClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(ClassA));
        var createMethod = genericType.GetMethod("CreateEntity");
        _myHandler = (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), null, createMethod);

        var result = _myHandler(5);
    }
}

class TestClass<T> where T : BaseEntity, new() {
    public T CreateEntity(long userId) {
        return new T() { CreateUserId = userId };
    }
}
```

This code throw exception.

Update 1: 
Fix the code to be understandable.

Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred
```

Comment: Full exception text and stack trace, please.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Issues: 1. You're trying to use a generic type without making a closed type. `TestClass<>` doesn't indicate to .NET what it should return as T, so how would it know? 2. You're trying to access an instance method of `TestClass<>` without first creating an instance to use.

Comment: @John I trying to declare a delegate. I have a generic class and this class use DTOs and I convert them my db objects. So I need to call this CreateEntity method with my new db entity type.

Comment: @PetSerAl yes because whatever except null, throw another example. What parameter pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
_myHandler = (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), null, createMethod);
```

The second parameter of the [overload of `.CreateDelegate` you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) takes an instance of the type to which the method belongs.

You should either make your method static, or create an instance of genericType:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
_myHandler = (MyDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), instance, createMethod);
```